# Using LINQ to select unknown values from files

Tags: c#, linq

I have several text files that have information within that relates to machine code. Below is a snippet of what is inside one of the files.

```
 <Parameter Name="Thickness" Idx="0" Val="0.8" Default="0.8" Min="0" Max="200" Show="True" Inherit="False" />
```

I am trying to use LINQ in order to extract information from this specific line of text. Here is what I have so far.

```
 var thickness = from t in text
                 where t.Contains("Thickness") && t.Contains("Idx=0") && t.Contains("Val")
                 select t;
```

I need to grab the 'Val' from this line of text, which should be 0.8 in this case. Please could someone enlighten me into how I can do this? I've done some research but I can't find a definitive answer.

Thank you.

Comment: Is the text file valid xml?  You probably want to use `XDocument`, then LINQ to query for your `Val` attribute.

Comment: @Jonesopolis It is a .PAR file that is valid XML.

Comment: If this is an XML, remember that XPath queries are still supported by `XmlDocument`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for your useful answers. I have taken them on board and appreciate the help.

I decided upon utilizing substrings. Please see the method I used below.

```
var _thickness = (from row in lines
                 where row.Contains("Thickness") && row.Contains("Idx=\"0\"")
                 select row).First();

int thickStartIndex = _thickness.IndexOf("Val=");
thickStartIndex = thickStartIndex + 5;
int thickEndIndex = _thickness.IndexOf("Default");
string thickValue = _thickness.Substring(thickStartIndex, thickEndIndex - thickStartIndex - 2);
```

Output = 0.8

Comment: Why this approach? Using `XDocument` is far more robust. What if the XML has more line breaks than you expect?

Comment: @GertArnold I agree with your comment and you are correct. However, I know what these files look like so I know that there won't be additional breaks. It's for an in-house project. I am also still learning so it's early days for me. Thanks for the advice :)

Answer (score 1):

this is an example as I understood, as you try to use linq instead of multiple EZ approaches
so now you can add any where condition and adjust select

```
void Main()
{
    string s= "<Parameter Name=\"Thickness\" Idx=\"0\" Val=\"0.8\" Default=\"0.8\" Min=\"0\" Max=\"200\" Show=\"True\" Inherit=\"False\" />";
    var doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.LoadXml(s);
    
    var attr = doc.FirstChild
                    .Attributes
                    .Cast<XmlAttribute>()
                    .ToList()
                    .Select(s=> $"{s.Name} == {s.Value}");
    Console.Write(attr);

}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Using `XDocument` you can convert the file to have a single root and then query with LINQ to XML.

First, convert the file to an `XDocument`. Note: If your file is very large or you don't want to read all the lines into memory and then create a single, very large string, you could use an `IEnumerable<string>` to `Stream` converter and `File.ReadLines()` to reduce the overhead.

If `srcFile1` contains the lines from your file, then create the `XElement` collection of the lines with:

```
var data1 = XDocument.Parse("<data>" + srcFile1.Join('\n') + "</data>").Root.Elements();
```

Note: `Join` is the obvious extension method.

Now you can query the lines and pull out the `Val` attribute value:

```
var ans = data1.Where(d => d.AttrVal("Name") == "Thickness" && d.AttrVal("Idx") == "0" && d.HasAttr("Val"))
               .Select(d => d.AttrVal("Val"))
               .ToList();
```

I used some simple extension methods to make it a bit shorter:

```
public static class XMLExt {
    public static string AttrVal(this XElement x, string name) => x.Attribute(name)?.Value;
    public static bool HasAttr(this XElement x, string name) => x.Attribute(name) != null;
}
```